# There was a boy on my left or left to me. What's the difference "on" and "to" here?

Tags: difference

1. There was no boy on my left/left to me.
2. Is there anyone to your right?/ on your right?
3. How many people were to Mamun's right?/on Mamun's right?

What's the difference "on" and "to" here? Which is correct?

Answer (score 3):

We don't say *right/left to me.*

*On my right* and *to my right* are both correct. If you have someone *on your right*, they are probably sitting or standing next to you; if they are *to your right*, they may be some distance away on that side.

Comment: You could also say "to the left of me".

Answer (score 2):

In many contexts "on the right" and "to the right" are interchangeable.

Perhaps "on the right" indicates a position "He sat on my right", but "to the right" indicates a direction "You can see the Eifell tower to the right".  But even in these, swapping the prepositions would be understandable.

You should not say "right to me" or "right on me" (with this sense of "right")

So "There was no boy on my right" suggests that the space next to you was empty (or there was a girl there).  But "There was no boy to the right of me" suggests that there were no boys in that general direction, not just immediately beside you.

But this distinction is only a vague suggestion, rather than a very strict rule